# Energizing a relay with a lower coil voltage than my power supply

Tags: relay, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, solid-state-relay

I'm using a 72 VDC power supply to drive some equipment. I need to drop that voltage down to 48 VDC to drive a [relay](https://catalog.weidmueller.com/catalog/Start.do?localeId=en&ObjectID=2476760000) I'm using.

What are my options to energize the relay coil and what specs do I use from the datasheet?

My initial idea is to do a simple voltage divider. I use the coil resistance from the datasheet (4300 ohm) as my R2 and that gives me an R1 of 2150 ohms (2200 ohm for a common value). As for specifying the power for the resistor it would be 24^2/2200 = 0.3 W ?

Answer (score 2):

Using a resistor will work as relays are fairly tolerant but if someone puts a similar relay in for some reason, the specs may be different. I’d suggest a simple transistor + zener diode regulator.
You’ll  probably want to use a heatsink as the transistor will probably get to around 30degreesC above ambient (your resistor would get hot as well unless you used a metal clad one and bolted it to a metal panel). The regulator will ensure the relay gets 48V without being dependent on the actual relay specs.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor will work fine. You could also use a 24V 1W zener diode (eg. [1N4749](https://my.centralsemi.com/datasheets/1N4728A-4764A.PDF)) if the 72V is reasonably well regulated.

That's an odd relay- they appear to use the coil (or maybe a second resistor?) as a voltage divider to derive a voltage for the indicator LED. The reverse voltage waveform across the LED at turn-off might be interesting if they are using part of the coil.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking up sample [Zener Regulator Circuit Diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgiHM.jpg) and I'm confused. Wouldn't I want a 48V Zener instead? Something like the 1N4756A from that same datasheet?  

RL in this case would be the relay itself for which I know the coil resistance, current, and voltage all from the datasheet?

Comment: The Zener would go in series (like a resistor) and would make the circuit **less** sensitive to relay coil resistance but **more** sensitive to variations on the  72V bus compared to using a resistor (+/-5% change in the 72V would represent +/-7.5% change at the relay). It just subtracts 24V from the applied voltage, it's not a regulator.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My [power supply](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/powersolutions/ds-bps-ldc480-series.pdf) is adjustable between 70-85VDC so there could be quite a bit of variation. Would you still recommend using the Zener in series?

Comment: If it actually varies that much the resistor would be preferable. But it looks rather well-regulated (0.5%) so if you intend to leave it at 72V then the zener would be a good way to go.

Comment: I've seen the voltage vary myself based on load and some derating when getting hot since it's passively cooled. 

When you say the "resistor would be preferable", you mean the Zener in parallel to the relay or a voltage divider circuit? Again I really appreciate the help

Comment: Just a series resistor will do it.

Comment: I voted for Spehro’s solution - a Zener diode in series - simple and works just that: Voltage Shifter, from 72V to 48V. If @fullyjosh desires to operate at different voltage, select a different Zener. However if the “72V power” is not defined or intends to vary greatly, then Kartman’s solution (48V Zener+resistor biasing an NPN transistor = simple series regulator) might be more flexible.